# Applying speed and number of rotations for CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, core-animation, uitouch, cabasicanimation

I am trying to mimic the rotation of the bottle in [Spin the Coke](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spin-the-coke/id303018470?mt=8) app and pie-chart in the [Roambie](http://itunes.apple.com/app/roambi-visualizer/id315020789?mt=8)  App. . I wanted to rotate a view as per the touches and swipes of the user on that view.

What I currently do it:

1. Get the time when a touch Began and ended. (and swipe)
2. Get all the coordinates of the touch or swipe and find the total distance.

I believe that the spin the coke app animates the bottles based on the distance and time taken for the swipe or touch. But I am not sure how they could have done.

I wanted the view to rotate faster initially, then slowdown and stop finally.

Please share your thoughts on how this problem could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at keyframe animation: you have to build your animation manually but you can achieve any result you want.